# Help with R and grouping/aggregate/*apply/data.table

Tags: r, data-visualization, average, ggplot2

I'm very new to R and having trouble running functions to get the answers I need. I have example data PCSTest

http://pastebin.com/z9Ti3nHB

that looks something like this:

```
Date        Site            Word
--------------------------------------
9/1/2012    slashdot        javascript
9/1/2012    stackexchange   R
9/1/2012    reddit          R
9/1/2012    slashdot        javascript
9/1/2012    stackexchange   javascript
9/5/2012    reddit          R
9/8/2012    slashdot        javascript
9/8/2012    stackexchange   R
9/8/2012    reddit          R
9/8/2012    slashdot        javascript
9/18/2012   stackexchange   R
9/18/2012   reddit          R
9/18/2012   slashdot        javascript
9/18/2012   stackexchange   R
9/27/2012   reddit          R
9/27/2012   slashdot        R
```

My goal is to looks for trends in the occurrences of different words as they relate to sites over time. I can count them:

```
library(plyr)   
PCSTest <- read.csv(file="c:/PCS/PCS Data - Test.csv", header=TRUE)
PCSTest$Date <- as.Date(PCSTest$Date, "%m/%d/%Y")
PCSTest$Date <- as.POSIXct(PCSTest$Date)
countTest <- count(PCSTest, c("Date", "Site", "Word"))
```

which gives this:

```
                  Date          Site       Word freq
1  2012-08-31 20:00:00        reddit          R    4
2  2012-08-31 20:00:00      slashdot javascript    7
3  2012-08-31 20:00:00 stackexchange javascript    1
4  2012-08-31 20:00:00 stackexchange          R    2
5  2012-09-01 20:00:00        reddit javascript    2
6  2012-09-01 20:00:00      slashdot          R    3
7  2012-09-04 20:00:00        reddit          R    1
8  2012-09-07 20:00:00        reddit          R    1
9  2012-09-07 20:00:00      slashdot javascript    2
10 2012-09-07 20:00:00 stackexchange          R    1
11 2012-09-09 20:00:00 stackexchange javascript    4
12 2012-09-10 20:00:00      slashdot          R    4
13 2012-09-14 20:00:00        reddit javascript    4
14 2012-09-17 20:00:00        reddit          R    4
15 2012-09-17 20:00:00      slashdot javascript    1
16 2012-09-17 20:00:00 stackexchange          R    2
17 2012-09-19 20:00:00        reddit javascript    2
18 2012-09-23 20:00:00 stackexchange javascript    2
19 2012-09-24 20:00:00        reddit javascript    3
20 2012-09-24 20:00:00 stackexchange javascript    1
21 2012-09-24 20:00:00 stackexchange          R    4
22 2012-09-25 20:00:00        reddit javascript    5
23 2012-09-25 20:00:00      slashdot javascript    3
24 2012-09-25 20:00:00 stackexchange          R    7
25 2012-09-26 20:00:00        reddit          R    1
26 2012-09-26 20:00:00      slashdot          R    5
```

or plot them all:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=countTest, aes(x=Date, y=freq, group=interaction(Site, Word), colour=interaction(Site, Word), shape=Site)) + geom_line() + geom_point()
```

[image: My plot of Frequency per day for Words per Site]

I need to do some calculations on the data now, so I've tried aggregate

```
aggregate(freq ~ Site + Word, data = countTest,  function(freq) cbind(mean(freq), max(freq)))[order(-agg$freq[,3]),]
```

which gives:

```
           Site       Word freq.1 freq.2
2      slashdot javascript   3.25   7.00
5      slashdot          R   4.00   5.00
1        reddit javascript   3.20   5.00
4        reddit          R   2.20   4.00
6 stackexchange          R   3.20   7.00
3 stackexchange javascript   2.00   4.00
```

What I would like in that last result is a column that has the average frequency per day, something like... sum(freq)/20 days, calculated from the data, maybe a moving average even.
Also, I would like another column with the slope/linear regression. How would I calculate that in the aggregate function?

Or, how would I make any of this better/faster? I know that there are apply and data.table functions but I don't see how I would use them. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you want to do exactly, but `dplyr` (or `plyr`) will help you.
Here is examples. If you tell explicitly what you want, you will get more helps.

```
d <- read.csv("~/Downloads/r_data.txt")
d$Date <- as.POSIXct(as.Date(d$Date, "%m/%d/%Y"))

library(dplyr)
d.cnt <- d %>% group_by(Date, Site, Word) %>% summarise(cnt = n())

# average per day
date.range <- d$Date %>% range %>% diff %>% as.numeric # gives 26 days or
date.range <- d$Date %>% unique %>% length # gives 13 days
d.ave <- d.cnt %>% group_by(Site, Word) %>% summarize(ave_per_day = sum(cnt)/date.range)

# slope
d.reg <- d.cnt %>% group_by(Site, Word) %>% 
  do({fit = lm(cnt ~ Date, data = .); data.frame(int = coef(fit)[1], slope = coef(fit)[2])})

# plot the slope value
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(d.reg, aes(Site, slope, fill = Word)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge")
```

Comment: @Oleg You mentioned that you want to get average frequency for 20 days in your question. If you want to specify the date range, you can use `filter()`. You are subsetting with `filter()`. Something like this. `filter(d, Date >= "2012-09-01", Date <= "2012-09-25")`